# How do I remove extra zeros in a dataframe column?

Tags: python, dataframe

I got a dataframe that contains data looking like:

```
 Date         Values
2016-12-31    13000000.0
2017-12-31   -45000000.0
2018-12-31   -129000000.0
2019-12-31    276000000.0
```

Is there a way to remove the last 3 zeros before the decimal point? So for example in the values column. the value is 13000000.0 I would like to remove 3 zeros so the number becomes: 13000.0 Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['Values'] = df['Values'] / 1000
```

Answer (score 3):

To remove 3 zeros you need to divide the column by 1000:

```
df['Values'] = df['Values'] / 1e3
```